# How to use com.fasterxml.jackson 2.8.1 and 2.6.5 in the same module of maven project?

Tags: maven, apache-spark, dependency-management, presto

I have a module which has `Spark 2.1.0` and `Presto 0.166`. 
Spark 2.1.0 requires `com.faster.xml` version 2.6.5 while Presto 0.166 requires 2.8.1 strictly. How Can I resolve the issue in the same pom.xml so  that I can run them in the same module?

Answer (score 1):

Simply specify the version of `com-fasterxml-jackson` in your pom file. The version specified here will override the versions in `Spark 2.1.0` and `Presto 0.166`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.facebook.presto</groupId>
    <artifactId>presto...</artifactId>
    <version>0.166</version>
</dependency>
```

Since, `Spark 2.1.0` can use `com.fasterxml.jackson 2.8.1`, you won't need 2 different versions of it in your module.

---

**Resources** -

- [Introduction to the Dependency Mechanism](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use multiple version(s) of same dependency in a single `pom.xml`, [exclude-dependency](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html) `com.faster.xml version` either from `Spark 2.1.0` or from `Presto 0.166`, for example:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.0</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
          <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to write a plugin for Presto? If so, the Presto SPI explicitly depends on only `jackson-annotations` and not the implementation. There should be no problem with using the newer version of the annotations with an older version of Jackson within your plugin. The version of Jackson used by the Presto engine can and will be different from the one used by your plugin as plugins are loaded in a separate class loader.

The Presto plugin system is designed to have very minimal dependencies and allow you to use whatever versions of libraries you want (as that is often necessary when writing a connector to a random system that uses older versions of libraries).